# C Struct Assigning to Struct Array

Tags: c, pointers, macros, struct, placeholder

I am trying to add a struct to an array of structs, however I'm getting an error: `Parse Issue: Expected expression`. Below is my code:

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "map.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    map(map_ss, char*, char*);

    map_init(map_ss, map);

    printf("Map has been initilized\n\n");

    // The error is over the next 3 lines
    add_pair(map, "first", "1");
    add_pair(map, "second", "2");
    add_pair(map, "third", "3");

    print_map(map);

    map_free(map);

    printf("\n\nMap has been freed.");

    return 0;
}
```

and `map.h`

```
#ifndef Data_Structures_map_h
#define Data_Structures_map_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define pair(key_t, value_t)                                                \
    typedef struct pair {                                                   \
        key_t key;                                                          \
        value_t value;                                                      \
    } pair

#define map(name, key_t, value_t)                                           \
    pair(key_t, value_t);                                                   \
    typedef struct name {                                                   \
        pair* pairs;                                                        \
        int capacity;                                                       \
        int size;                                                           \
    } name

#define map_init(name, var_name)                                            \
    name* var_name = malloc(sizeof(var_name));                              \
    var_name->pairs = malloc(10 * sizeof(var_name->pairs));                 \
    var_name->capacity = 10;                                                \
    var_name->size = 0

#define map_free(var_name)                                                  \
    free(var_name)

#define add_pair(var_name, key, value)                                      \
    if (var_name->size == var_name->capacity)                               \
        var_name->pairs = realloc(var_name->pairs, 2 * var_name->capacity); \
    var_name->pairs[var_name->size++] = { .key = key, .value = value; }     \ // error in here

#define print_map(var_name)                                                 \
    printf("Contents of the map:\n");                                       \
    int i;                                                                  \
    for (i = 0; i < var_name->size; i++) {                                  \
        printf("Item #%i: Key:%p -> Value:%p\n",                            \
            (i+1), var_name->pairs[i].key, var_name->pairs[i].value);       \
    }                                                                       \

#endif /* Data_Structures_map_h */
```

I tried, `var_name->pairs[var_name->size++] = { key, value; }` and `pair p; p.key = key; p.value = value; var_name->pairs[var_name->size++] = p;`, but still not working. What is the problem here, it seems like it should work.

Also, is there a placeholder that will write anything to it, I read on Wikipedia that `%p` is for `void*` so I though it could work.

I am using Xcode on Mac.

Comment: Horrible, horrible, use of macros.

Comment: `pair p; p.key = key; p.value = value; var_name->pairs[var_name->size++] = p;, but still not working. What is the problem here` name of the macro argument is duplicated (with struct member).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#define add_pair(var_name, _key, _value)                                    \
    if (var_name->size == var_name->capacity)                               \
        var_name->pairs = realloc(var_name->pairs, 2 * var_name->capacity); \
    var_name->pairs[var_name->size].key = _key;                             \
    var_name->pairs[var_name->size++].value = _value
```

Comment: This worked, but why did I have to change from `key` to `_key` and from `value` to `_value`?

Comment: @aizen92 Member name and macro argument is a duplicate. E.g. `pair p; p.key = key;` macro expand -->> `pair p; p."key" = "key";`

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's merely a formatting issue, looks to me like you've got the semicolon on the wrong side of the curly brace in `{ .key = key, .value = value; }`.

Should be  `{ .key = key, .value = value };` instead.

Comment: Yeh, the semi-colon was misplaced, but even without it, or after `{` I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can't have anonymous struct initializer expressions, how should the compiler know what type that has?

Assuming you're using C99, the syntax is:

```
((pair) {.key = key, .value = value});
```

See for instance [gcc's documentation on compound literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).